# angularjs old input field value overriding new input value using scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

html:

```
username: <input type="text" ng-model="username" /><br />
password: <input type="text" ng-model="password" /><br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
```

js:

```
$scope.login = function(){
    var user = $scope.username;
    var pass = $scope.password;
    if(user != undefined && pass != undefined){
    alert("NOT BLANK" + " user: " + user + " pass: " + pass);
    } else {
    alert("BLANK");
    }
};
```

Question:
When I click Login for the first time with input values from the 2 fields, alert is showing NOT BLANK  user: test pass: value, but when I remove the values from the fields and click Login, alert shows NOT BLANK user: pass: which is not correct since the fields values have been removed. If I refresh the page, and click Login, alert will show BLANK. I think it is issue with cache. can someone help. I am novice with angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Cache Issue. By checking with `!= undefined` all you do is check if the String or Variable was defined - but it still can be an empty String.

So basically what happens is: you enter something, and the two Strings for `user` and `pass` get initialized. From this time, a check for `undefined` will always return false.
When you remove all letters, the two Variables still contain a String-Object, just without characters (basically like this: `var user = ''`).

Change your code to the following, that should work:

```
$scope.login = function(){
   var user = $scope.username;
   var pass = $scope.password;
   if(!user && !pass){
      alert("BLANK");
   } else {

     alert("NOT BLANK" + " user: " + user + " pass: " + pass);
 }
};
```

Comment: Does not work! When click on Login without any values from the fields, I get NOT BLANK user: undefined pass: undefined. When I enter values onto the fields, then press Login, I get BLANK

Answer (score 0):

The checks `user != undefined && pass != undefined)` are too stringent.

You should check for empty strings: `user === '' && pass === ''`.

**Update:**

Initialize the values such that they are initially not `undefined` either:

```
var user = $scope.username || '';
var pass = $scope.password || '';
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It will always display BLANK and will not go into the if statement

Comment: I changed to the following js script and it works.
    
js:

    $scope.login = function(){
        var user = $scope.username;
        var pass = $scope.password;
        if(user && pass){
           alert("NOT BLANK" + " user: " + user + " pass: " + pass);
        } else {
           alert("BLANK");
        }
    };

Comment: @user3420947 I have updated the answer and I would consider using more concrete types for your variables instead of relying on _falsy_ values. I have been burned by a valid value being '0' oft enough. :-)